# React map function is not returning items from an object array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created an array which contains objects and I want to loop through it using the map function and return the items inside that array. For some reason, the items are not returning. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
const SideNavItem = () => {
  const items = [
    {
      icon: 'home',
      link: '/',
      name: 'Home',
    },
    {
      icon: 'apple',
      link: '/',
      name: 'About',
    },
    {
      icon: 'angelist',
      link: '/',
      name: 'Support',
    },
  ];

  const itemlisting = () => {
    return items.map((item, i) => {
      return (
        <div key={i}>
          <Link to={item.link}>
            <FontAwesome name={item.icon} />
            {item.name}
          </Link>
        </div>
      );
    });
  };

  return <div>{itemlisting}</div>;
};

export default SideNavItem;
```

Comment: do you get any errors? the code looks fine.

Comment: Where is your render() ?

Comment: I though render was only suppose to be used on class components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gotcha...!

Solution1: you have defined `itemlisting` as a function. You have defined it but not called it in your return statement.
So you have to have your return statement as below.

```
return(
  <div>
    {itemlisting()}
  </div>
)
```

Solution 2: (OR) you could change your `itemlisting` as below. It doesn't need to be a function. Just an array.

```
const itemlisting = items.map((item, i) => {
  return (
    <div key={i}>
      <Link to={item.link}>
        <FontAwesome name={item.icon} />
        {item.name}
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
});
```

Comment: Yes thank you! Got to remember to always call functions.